# Working with promises and WebSockets in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, websocket, angular-promise

I have this JS code:

```
app.factory('ChatWebsocket', function ($q, ChatSocketUrl)
{
    var socket = new WebSocket(ChatSocketUrl);

    return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
        socket.onopen = function () {
            resolve(socket);
        };
        socket.onerror = function (e) {
            reject(e);
        }
    });
});

app.factory('ChatServiceWebsocket', function ($q, ChatWebsocket)
{
    function SocketWrapper(socket, action, payload)
    {
        return $q(function (resolve) {
            socket.onmessage = function (e) {
                resolve(JSON.parse(e.data));
            };

            socket.send(JSON.stringify({action: action, payload: payload}));
        });
    }

    return {
        login: function (userId, subjectId) {
            return ChatWebsocket.then(function (socket) {
                return new SocketWrapper(socket, 'login', {user: userId, subject: subjectId});
            });
        },
        rooms: function (userId) {
            return ChatWebsocket.then(function (socket) {
                return new SocketWrapper(socket, 'rooms', {user: userId});
            });
        }
    };
});


/******************* THE CONTROLLER ***************************/

ChatServiceWebsocket.rooms(userId).then(function (result) {
    console.log('ChatServiceWebsocket.rooms = ', result);
});

ChatServiceWebsocket.login(userId, roomId).then(function (result) {
    console.log('ChatServiceWebsocket.login = ', result);
});
```

I'm expecting to see in the console:

```
ChatServiceWebsocket.rooms = [Object ... room list]
ChatServiceWebsocket.login = [Object ... login data]
```

But instead I see only last call, with invalid output:

```
ChatServiceWebsocket.login = [Object ... room list]
```

Can't get this ChatServiceWebsocket to work properly :(

Comment: Could it be, that you use one single instance of ChatWebsocket. If you call login, perhaps, the promise of rooms is overwriten. if then the promise is completed, only the second function is called, with result from first query.

I cant verify this currently... but perhaps this gives you a possible hint.

Or not. ;)

Comment: I need to reuse the WebSocket connection so it won't reconnect each time to the service.

Comment: I don't know if this is correct, but the ChatWebsocket create one socket, this is OK. But it looks, it also creates only ONE promise ?
Can you try to add an function to ChatWebsocket, for a new Request, and this function should return a new $q promise for each request....

If you can provide a working fiddle oder something... i could try to show you, what I mean.

Comment: I'll try that for sure

Comment: Look into RxJS, the Observables are better fit for websockets than promises. I promise ;)

Comment: Well I wanted to avoid further dependencies and stick to Angular only.

Comment: And this is good. Remember that Angular promise are integrated in Angulars Execution loop.... That can be importend for further handling.

Comment: Well since there only can be one `onmessage` event defined on the WebSocket object, I manage to execute the code properly with nested promises so they execute in order https://jsfiddle.net/8d145cgq/3/ Thanks for your help